# Getters validation Symfony2 Error

Tags: validation, symfony, getter

I did all that is described in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters for validate a field and my code is:

```
public function isPasswordEasy() {
    if (in_array($this->password, array('123456', '1234', '12345', 'abc', '123'))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

getters:
    passwordEasy:
        - 'True': { message: "La contraseña es muy sencilla..." }
```

All it's ok, when I put in my text field '123' the getter 'passwordEasy' works fine because the function return true, but when put another characters that are not in the array the function return false and the follow message appears: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Somebody knows what is happening?

Comment: Please post the code of the action in your controller. It is most likely a missing return statement in a code path in your action.

Comment: Your error is almost for sure in the controller. You might not send a response when a form is valid.

Comment: Btw you can also `return in_array($this->password, array('123456', '1234', '12345', 'abc', '123'));` ;)

Comment: Really! my crontroller was wrong... I forget to do a return statement when is valid, I'm sorry but I was very tired and I couldn't see the problem, Thank you very much for your help! and thanks @bartek for the tip!